# generate image from base64 string

Tags: apex, visualforce, base64

We are trying to generate barcodes on the pdf without using any external site. I have the generated base64 string which i am calling on my vf page to generate the image of barcode. My barcode is not generating with below code.

**Controller -**

```
public  string base64Image{get;set;}

 base64Image ='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';
```

**VF page -**

```
 <apex:image value="data:image/png;base64,{base64Image}" styleClass="barcodeFirst" />
```

[image]

Comment: Please keep the original code/markup in your question. If you edit it to incorporate things from answers, then the answers lose context and don't make much sense. If you think that you must incorporate feedback from an answer, you should add it as a new section to your question (i.e. you would add another `<apex:image>` code block under the "broken image" in your question).

Answer (score 1):

Merge fields need to be in the form of `{!...}`. You forgot the `!`:

```
<apex:image value="data:image/png;base64,{!base64Image}" styleClass="barcodeFirst" />
```

Comment: I used it but not working. @sfdcfox

Comment: @SalesforceKid Yeah, looks like there's an [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhkhUAB/support-inline-data-uri-scheme-images-for-pdf-output-in-visualforce-pages) for this. In the meantime, workaround would be to render client-side with html2pdf.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using a barcode font. Much cleaner and easier solution.
Depending on the standard you can choose it from https://fonts.google.com/?query=barcode.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure you'd be able to use a custom font for a PDF, though. Salesforce PDF doesn't like custom fonts.

Comment: You might be right if he is trying to use Visualforce PDF Rendering [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm]